# How to use https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

Using the Google API explorer I can generate the following command, but don't understand how I can use this in a script?  I am a complete noob and don't even know where to begin.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/XXXXXXX/devices/mobile?fields=status&key={YOUR_API_KEY}  This would output all of the mobile devices in my domain.  I can create the API project and authenticate it.  I am specifically wondering how to I turn the above get command into a script?  Do I use the Python install I have?

Comment: Learn how to send an HTTP request in the language of your choice.

Comment: After hours of searching I found this Youtube video that appears to be the answer!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVjZMIWhz3Y